# Cannot set text and add attachment in JavaMail

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I am new to java mail and I am trying to send an email with Text and attachment.So below is my code

```
String mail = "";          //enter email id
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mail));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
InternetAddress.parse(MailReceipients.get(i)));
message.setSubject("Notification Mail");
MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
Multipart mp1 = new MimeMultipart();
attachment.attachFile("D;/file1.csv");
message.setText("Dear Sir/Madam,"+ "\n\n My Testing App Mail!");
mp1.addBodyPart(attachment);
message.setContent(mp1);
Transport.send(message);
```

But this only sends the attachment but not the text. But if set content first and then `setText` then it sends only the text. Could not figure out why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: should be `D:/file1.csv` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your multipart message needs two parts.](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#attach)  The first part is the main message body.  The second part is the attachment.

See the JavaMail [sendfile.java](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/sendfile.java) sample program.